# Compare two images and have the output print statement labelling reflect the samples being compared

Tags: python, macos, label, output, jupyter

I am not sure what the correct terminology would be in order to find a solution online.

I have two folders file 1 and file 2. In each folder for this example I have only be using six images in each folder. However, once I have the code fixed I want to compare a few hundred images.

The exact same files are in both folders.

My code works perfectly to compare each file and display the results but the labelling does not match the output results.

```
    compare_image_files(imgA[0], imgA[0])
    compare_image_files(imgA[0], imgB[0])
    compare_image_files(imgA[0], imgB[1])
    compare_image_files(imgA[0], imgB[2])
    compare_image_files(imgA[0], imgB[3])
    compare_image_files(imgA[0], imgB[4])
    compare_image_files(imgA[0], imgB[5])
```

[image: Print Statement]

My code is not elegant but it works except for the labelling:

```
    %matplotlib inline
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from pathlib import Path
    from IPython.display import Image, display
    from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error as mse
    from skimage.measure import compare_ssim as ssim
    import numpy as np
    from skimage import data
    from skimage import exposure
    from skimage.transform import match_histograms
    import os, glob
    import cv2


     path = '/Users/minnymouse/Documents/AAA_TEST_FILES_AUDIO/EXP_1_MULTI_FIBER/'
     #print(os.path.isdir(path))

     from matplotlib import rcParams
     rcParams['axes.titlepad'] = 20 

     source = '/Users/minnymouse/Documents/AAA_TEST_FILES_AUDIO/EXP_1_MULTI_FIBER/file1/'
     #print(os.listdir(reference))
     #print(os.path.isdir(source))
     #print(os.listdir(source_images))

     source_images = glob.iglob(source + "*.png")



     for source_file in source_images:

         source_head, tail = os.path.splitext(source_file)

         im = cv2.imread(source_file)

         imgA = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


         #fig = plt.figure()

         #source_image = plt.imshow(img)

         #plt.axis("off")

    reference = 
         '/Users/minnymouse/Documents/AAA_TEST_FILES_AUDIO/EXP_1_MULTI_FIBER/file2/'


     reference_images = glob.iglob(reference + "*.png")

    #print(os.listdir(reference_images))

    for ref_file in reference_images:

        ref_head, tail = os.path.splitext(ref_file)

        im = cv2.imread(ref_file)

        imgB = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        #fig = plt.figure()

        #ref_image = plt.imshow(img)

        #plt.axis("off")

    def compare_image_files(imgA, imgB):

        m = mse(imgA, imgB)

        s = ssim(imgA, imgB)

        print("Source File: " + os.path.basename(source_head), "is compared to " + 
    os.path.basename(ref_head), "= ", "MSE: %.2f, SSIM: %.2f" % (m, s))


        return m, s
```

I think the issue is os.path.basename or how I set up my 'for' statement for the two folders. I really don't know, which makes this really hard to trouble shoot. 
Thanks for any help.

I am a Mac 10.14.6 using Jupyter with Python3

Comment: your problem is that you don't send names as arguments - `compare_image_files(imgA, imgB, filename1, filenam2):`. and you would have to keep names with images - `(image, filename)` - on the list. Using `source_head, tail = ...` you can keep only last value from loop.

Comment: other problem can be that you don't keep images on lists and `imgA`, `imgB` can keep only last images and using `imgA[0]`, `imgB[0]` you compare two rows from files, not two files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you dont use lists to keep images with names. You read images and you assign always to the same variable so you remove previous image. SO finaly in `imgA` and `imgB` you have only single images. And `source_head`, `refe-head` keeps only only last names. And `imgA[0]`, `imgB[0]` gets first rows from two images, `imgA[1]`, `imgB[1]` gets seconds rows from the same two images, etc.

You need

```
# ---

all_source_images = []

source_images = glob.iglob(source + "*.png")

for source_file in source_images:
     source_head, tail = os.path.splitext(source_file)
     im = cv2.imread(source_file)
     imgA = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

     all_source_images.append( [imgA, source_head] )

# ---

all_ref_images = []

reference_images = glob.iglob(reference + "*.png")

for ref_file in reference_images:
    ref_head, tail = os.path.splitext(ref_file)
    im = cv2.imread(ref_file)
    imgB = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    all_ref_images.append( [imgB, ref_head] )
```

and now you have two lists with images and they names - `all_source_images`, `all_ref_images`.

And now you would have to use nested `for`-loops to work with these lists.

```
for image_A, filename_A in all_source_images:
    for image_B, filename_B in all_ref_images:
        compare_image_files(image_A, image_B, filename_A, filename_B)
```

And you should send names as arguments too

```
def compare_image_files(imgA, imgB, nameA, nameB):
    m = mse(imgA, imgB)
    s = ssim(imgA, imgB)

    print("Source File: %s is compared to %s = MSE: %.2f, SSIM: %.2f" % (os.path.basename(nameA), os.path.basename(nameB), m, s))

    return m, s
```

Comment: Thank you. Thank you. Thank you!!! I have been starring at this for two days. It works perfectly.  
My only question is, would it possible to not have the file ext .png at the end of the label, please?  Other than that. Thank you. Thank you. Thank you.

Comment: simply use `source_head` instead of `source_file` in `all_source_images.append( [imgA, source_file] )`.  The same with other list.

Comment: I put `source_head` instead of  `source_file` in current code in answer. The same with other list.

Comment: The output looks so pretty. Thank you! I can't stop looking at it. So happy.